# Evento click no tiene funcion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

He creado botones dinamicos y les he asignado un evento click pero al momento de clickearlos, no entran en el evento

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

        Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
        var name = Btn_clic.Text;

        List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
        List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

        List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

        List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

        var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
            newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
            newButton.Text = team;

            newButton.Click += Info_Click;

            newButton.OnClientClick = "return ModalGood();";
            Botones.Add(newButton);

            GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
            newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
        }
    }
protected void Info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button Btnclick = (Button)sender;
            var team = Btnclick.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.TEAM == "516" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM);
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }
```

he colocado breakpoints y de plano no entra, puse manualmente un boton para verificar que mi evento estaba bien y en efecto esta bien...

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que la carga dinámica de botones la estas haciendo en el evento `Load` de la página, si esto es correcto debes pasar tú código para el evento `Init` para que te pueda funcionar:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{      
    foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
        newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
        newButton.Text = team;
        newButton.Click += Info_Click;

        //newButton.OnClientClick = "return ModalGood();";
        Botones.Add(newButton);

        GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
        newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
    }   
}
```

> **Actualización de la respuesta**

Hice este ejemplo para que lo ensayes dentro de tu proyecto

**HTML dentro de la página .aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>    
            <asp:Button ID="Unnamed1" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" Text="Area" />
            <asp:Panel ID="GoodPanel" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>    
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        Session["Btn_clic"] = null;

    if (Session["Btn_clic"] == null)
        return;

    Button Btn_clic = Session["Btn_clic"] as Button;        
    if (Btn_clic.ID == Unnamed1.ID)
        CrearBotones(Btn_clic.Text);        
}

protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Session["Btn_clic"] = btn;
    CrearBotones(btn.Text);
}

protected void Info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Text = (sender as Button).ID;
}

private void CrearBotones(string area)
{
    //TODO: acá implementas tú otra parte del código

    var TeamFCH = new string[] { "TEAM1", "TEAM2", "TEAM3", "TEAM4" };
    foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
        newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
        newButton.Text = team;
        newButton.Click += Info_Click;
        GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
        newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, de echo, la carga dinamica la inicio al dar clic sobre un boton

Comment: he editado mi pregunta con todo el codigo, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta con un ejemplo, ensayalo y me cuentas como te va.

Comment: He estudiado e implementado tu codigo pero me temo que sigue con el mismo error